# Exclude GET Parameters from indexed_search results

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

I would like to exlude some GET Parameters of the search results of indexed_search and didn't find a configuration for this, yet. Can someone help me out?

Example:

/test.html?foo=bar

Should result in just:

/test.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the problem by adding those parameters to `[FE][cHashExcludedParameters]` in the install tool.